# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.90"

Tags: java, android, paypal-sandbox

Im following a tutorial for a food order app, and I add integrated PayPal Payment. So if I click on my FButton:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Abschicken", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //get comment adress from alert Dialog
            adress = edtAddress.getText().toString();
            comment = edtComment.getText().toString();

            String formatAmount = txtTotalPrice.getText().toString()
                                    .replace("€","")
                                    .replace(",","")
                                    .replaceAll("\\s+","");

            PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(formatAmount),"EUR","Pizza App Order", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), PaymentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);

            }


        });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if(confirmation != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    String paymentDetail = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(paymentDetail);


                    //CREATE NEW REQUEST
                    Request request = new Request(
                            Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                            Common.currentUser.getName(),
                            adress,
                            txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                            "0",
                            comment,
                            jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getString("state"),
                            cart
                    );

                    //Submit to Firebase
                    requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                            .setValue(request);
                    //DeleteCart
                    new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
                    Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Vielen Dank! Ihre Bestellung wurde soeben abgeschickt!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Zahlung abgebrochen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fehler!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void loadListFood() {
    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart, this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Calculate total
    int total = 0;
    for (Order order:cart)
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));

}
```

I got this crash error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: de.pizza, PID: 29841
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.pizza/de.pizza.Cart}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.90"
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.90"
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
>           at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
>           at de.pizza.Cart.loadListFood(Cart.java:212)
>           at de.pizza.Cart.onCreate(Cart.java:102)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

I tried first to use "," in my prices, but same resuelt but in error code

> For input string: "4,90"

If I remove all "." or ",", and I will have a total of 8€, I will get in PayPal Sandbox a total price of 800€.

If this could be useful to help me to solve my problem:

CartAdapter.java

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(""+listData.get(position).getQuantity(), Color.RED);
    holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
    holder.txt_price.setText(fmt.format(price));
    holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());
}
```

**UPDATE**

> Changed `Integer.parseInt` to `Double.parseDouble`

Result:
If I use decimal prices, total price is Integer.

Like: 
Is 4.10€+4.00=8.00€ or 8.90€+4.50=12.00€
should 4.10€+4.00=8.10€ or 8.90€+4.50=13.40€

Actual Code:

Cart.java

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Abschicken", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            //get comment adress from alert Dialog
            adress = edtAddress.getText().toString();
            comment = edtComment.getText().toString();

            String formatAmount = txtTotalPrice.getText().toString()
                                    .replace("€","")
                                    .replace(",",".")
                                    .replaceAll("\\s+","");

            PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(formatAmount),"EUR","Pizzeria Bacco Usingen App Order", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
            Intent intent = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), PaymentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
            startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);

            }


        });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if(confirmation != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    String paymentDetail = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(paymentDetail);


                    //CREATE NEW REQUEST
                    Request request = new Request(
                            Common.currentUser.getPhone(),
                            Common.currentUser.getName(),
                            adress,
                            txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                            "0",
                            comment,
                            jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getString("state"),
                            cart
                    );

                    //Submit to Firebase
                    requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                            .setValue(request);
                    //DeleteCart
                    new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
                    Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Vielen Dank! Ihre Bestellung wurde soeben abgeschickt!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Zahlung abgebrochen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fehler!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void loadListFood() {
    cart = new Database(this).getCarts();
    adapter = new CartAdapter(cart, this);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Calculate total
    int total = 0;
    for (Order order:cart)
        total+=(Double.parseDouble(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));

}
```

CartAdapter.java

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(""+listData.get(position).getQuantity(), Color.RED);
    holder.img_cart_count.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    double price = (Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
    //int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
    holder.txt_price.setText(fmt.format(price));
    holder.txt_cart_name.setText(listData.get(position).getProductName());
}
```

Comment: Your crash is caused by ``` total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))...```. It is a bad practice to use ```parseInt``` when you're dealing with prices, because, one usually prices are not int values, usually they are float values, second, the price is locale dependent and it can have a different format based on the locale. You should check ```NumberFormat``` for parsing the price.

Comment: `4.90` is obviously not a valid int. It is a `float` at least. Therefore you can't parse it into the int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing 4.90 which is not an Integer, so you of course can't parse it as Integer.

Either use `Double.parseDouble` or `Float.parseFloat` instead.

Comment: Sir, soirry, i dont get it. Where exactly should I use Double.parseDouble or Float.parseFloat, cause the Quantity should be Integer? Thanks

Comment: `(Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity())` either of this value is decimal, so if you use integer.parseint it will throw numberformat exception. try using double.parsedouble for both.

Comment: @iaef11 How can you pretend 4.90 to be an integer?! It's actually "four AND ninety". And... it seems to me that you're getting the **price**, not the **quantity**. Or you're making a mess with that: *price (float/double) * quantity (integer) = total price (float/double)*

Comment: So, I used Double.parseDouble, and didn't got an error, but the Total Price in the cart shows 9,00€ (4,90€ + 5,00€), which should be 9,40. And in PayPal SandBox I got an total price of 900€. I tried Float.parseFloat, and got same problem. What could be the reason for the Price which get multiplied with 100 in PayPal Sandbox??

Comment: @iaef11 maybe it's **cents**, instead of being **euro**? Then, reasoning by integers would be correct. and, by the way, `4.90 + 5.00 = 9.90, not 9.00` - maybe you're calculating only the integer part, without considering the decimal one. That would give you `9.00`.

Comment: oh, sorry!Mixed up... So what can I do?

Comment: @iaef11 Fix the mix.

Comment: it is due to you are converting your result to int at last `int price`, you should use double instead `double price`

Comment: Updated! Pls check! Result: If I use decimal prices, total price = Integer.

Like: Is 4.10€+4.00=8.00€ or 8.90€+4.50=12.00€ should 4.10€+4.00=8.10€ or 8.90€+4.50=13.40€

Comment: Then, as I said in a previous comment, you are only taking the integer part of the number.

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt does not expect ","

From : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
int price = (Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
```

To this:

```
double price = (Double.parseDouble(listData.get(position).getPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getQuantity()));
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried Double.parseDouble, and didn't got an error, but the Total Price in the cart shows 9,00€ (4,90€ + 5,00€), which should be 9,40. And in PayPal SandBox I got an total price of 900€. I tried Float.parseFloat, and got same problem. What could be the reason for the Price which get multiplied with 100 in PayPal Sandbox?

Comment: @iaef11 put a break point at this line debug the app and when app stops at break point press alt key and click on `getPrice()` and `getQuantity()` and see the result values